# Convert from Bool to boolean

Tags: java

I calling to method with get.bool and getting bool value and 
I need to update other method which needs to get type of boolean(
Value.setValue( )) ,

```
Bool aa = Entry.getBool();



Value.setValue(aa );
```

since I using aa i getting message 
The method setValue(Boolean) in the type BooleanValue is not applicable for the arguments (Bool)

how should i do this casting?

Comment: There is no class `Bool` in Java. You need to give a bit more context.

Comment: Bool is not a standard Java type. Without its javadoc or source code, it's impossible for us to know what it is.

Comment: There might be a method on Bool to get the PDT.  Something like aa.getBoolean() comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what he's trying to do is convert a Boolean to boolean (the primitive). if that's the case, this is how you could do it:

```
//Construct a Boolean object.
Boolean blnObj = new Boolean("true");

//use booleanValue of Boolean class to convert it into boolean primitive
boolean b = blnObj.booleanValue();
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: That doesn't fit the error message: `The method setValue(Boolean) in the type BooleanValue is not applicable for the arguments (Bool)`

Comment: Until he actually gives us a bit more context on what he's really trying to do, it's all a bit of guess work. ;-)